# Find word in string Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of strings:

```
s1 = 'user-1 color-class';
s2 = 'text-class user-1 color-class";
s3 = 'text-class not-user-1 color-class";
s4 = 'not-user-1 color-class";
s5 = 'not-user-1 user-1 color-class";
```

I want to return true or false for all the strings that contain the word starting with `player-`. That is, not as part of another word, but starting with.

So for the above

```
s1 = 'user-1 color-class';  <-- TRUE
s2 = 'text-class user-1 color-class";  <-- TRUE
s3 = 'text-class not-user-1 color-class";  <-- FALSE
s4 = 'not-user-1 color-class";  <-- FALSE
s5 = 'not-user-1 user-1 color-class";  <-- TRUE
```

So for example:

```
if (hasUserClass(string)) {           <-- boolean
```

Additionally, how do I get the `user-X` value from the class string?

```
userClass = getUserClass(string);     <-- `user-3`
```

Thanks

This is what I have done so far:

```
function getUserClass(element)
{
    if (! element) {
        return false;
    }

    var classes = $(element).attr('class');

    if (classes.search('user-') == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    return classes.match(/player\-\d+/gi)[0];
}


function userHasClass(element)
{
    if (! element) {
        return false;
    }

    var userClass = getUserClass(element);

    return (userClass == active_user.class);
}
```

But this does not take into account is must be the start of the word matched.

Comment: what's about googling this : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/startsWith

Comment: Like this: `s.split(" ").find(function(str) { return str.startsWith("user-"); });` ?

Comment: can you show what you've done so far? Where your stuck?

Comment: 4 out of your 5 strings have a syntax error. Opening with `'` and closing with `"`.

Comment: english version of orcusz link jic : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: @Patrick2607 What about `s.split(" ").some( str => str.startsWith("user-") )` ? `some` will return true or false.

Comment: "I want to return true or false for all the strings that contain the word starting with player-" is user-1 a player ?

Comment: @JeremyThille even better :)

Comment: "Additionally, how do I get the user-X value from the class string?". When there is are more then one "user-1" "user-2", what you wanted to return?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an ES6 one-liner.

```js
s1 = 'user-1 color-class'; //<-- TRUE
s2 = 'text-class user-1 color-class';  //<-- TRUE
s3 = 'text-class not-user-1 color-class';  //<-- FALSE
s4 = 'not-user-1 color-class';  //<-- FALSE
s5 = 'not-user-1 user-1 color-class';  //<-- TRUE

const myTest = words => words.split(" ").some( str => str.startsWith("user-") )

console.log(myTest(s1), myTest(s2) ,myTest(s3), myTest(s4), myTest(s5))
```

Comment: Pffff if only. I wish I was.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant starting with `user-`.

```
txt.split(' ').some((elem) =>  elem.startsWith('user-'));
```

will give you what you need

Answer (score 0):

Just use `indexOf`. But why not pass `active_user.class` directly?

```js
var s1 = 'user-1 color-class';
var s2 = 'text-class user-1 color-class';
var s3 = 'text-class not-user-1 color-class';
var s4 = 'not-user-1 color-class';
var s5 = 'not-user-1 user-1 color-class';

var test1 = 'user-';
var test2 = 'user-1'; // effectively active_user.class
var test3 = 'user-2';

function check (pWhat, pAgainst) {
    var w = ' ' + pWhat;
    var a = ' ' + pAgainst;
    return w.indexOf (a) >= 0;
}

console.log("aginst: " + test1);
console.log(s1 + " -> " + check(s1,  test1));
console.log(s2 + " -> " + check(s2,  test1));
console.log(s3 + " -> " + check(s3,  test1));
console.log(s4 + " -> " + check(s4,  test1));
console.log(s5 + " -> " + check(s5,  test1));

console.log("aginst: " + test2);
console.log(s1 + " -> " + check(s1,  test2));
console.log(s2 + " -> " + check(s2,  test2));
console.log(s3 + " -> " + check(s3,  test2));
console.log(s4 + " -> " + check(s4,  test2));
console.log(s5 + " -> " + check(s5,  test2));

console.log("aginst: " + test3);
console.log(s1 + " -> " + check(s1,  test3));
console.log(s2 + " -> " + check(s2,  test3));
console.log(s3 + " -> " + check(s3,  test3));
console.log(s4 + " -> " + check(s4,  test3));
console.log(s5 + " -> " + check(s5,  test3));
```

Answer (score -1):

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Take a look to this.

if you use

```
var str = "Hello world, welcome to the universe.";
var n = str.indexOf("welcome");
var m = str.indexOf("itDoesntExist");

console.log(n)  // prints 13
console.log(m) //  prints -1 since it doesnt exist
```

later you can use an `if` statement with it.

like

```
if(m === -1) { console.log("it doesnt exist ") };
```

Comment: Thanks but does not work for `str = "hellowelcome hi there" it will return true for `welcome` but it is not the start of the welcome word.

Comment: So you only want it to return true if a word starts with "player" or only if "player" exists alone without any addition  ?

Comment: This returns numbers, not true or false. Besides, `text-class not-user-1 color-class` will pass the test.

Comment: @JeremyThille read the rest of the answer. you can also check again in an if condition  if the return value is -1 or not. but ok do as you wish to.